# $\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^xf(i\cdot j)$ Double Summing a (Not Completely) Multiplicative Function

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algorithms, computer-science, divisors-multiples

Let $f(n)$ be a multiplicative function that is **not** completely multiplicative, i.e $f(m)\cdot f(n)= f(m\cdot n)$ only if $gcd(m,n)=1$. Let $S(x)$ be the double sum over $f$, that is:

$$S(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^xf(i\cdot j)$$

It is not difficult to see that if $f(n)$ were completely multiplicative, then $S(x)$ could be simplified:

$$S(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^xf(i\cdot j)= \sum_{i=1}^xf(i)\sum_{j=1}^xf(j)= \biggl(\sum_{k=1}^xf(k)\biggr)^2$$

But since $f(n)$ is not completely multiplicative, this simplification is not completely true, and it fails in every combination where $gcd(i,j)\neq1$. Hence, $S(x)$ can be written this way provided we add some additional error term, let's call it $E$:

$$S(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^xf(i\cdot j)= \biggl(\sum_{k=1}^xf(k)\biggr)^2+E$$

$E$ is either negative or positive, I'm not sure. Obviously, $E$ is comprised of all the small errors generated by the initial sum term, when $gcd(i,j)\neq1$. I am mainly interested in the cases where $f(n)$ takes the form of:

1. Euler totient function: $$S_{\varphi}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^x\varphi(i\cdot j)$$
2. Sum of divisors function: $$S_{\sigma_1}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^x\sigma_1(i\cdot j)$$
3. Moebius function: $$S_{\mu}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^x\mu(i\cdot j)$$

My question is, what is this error term $E$ exactly? how can I calculate it? How can I properly sum all those small errors to get a correct evaluation of $S(x)$? For clarification, I am concerned with evaluating $S(x)$, but I think I must evaluate $E$ first in order to do it. I am taking this approach because I can compute $\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^xf(k)\biggr)^2$ very efficiently, and so, finding the error term $E$ will solve my question.

Comment: This is a copy of my original post on MSE, in attempt to get an answer. Here's the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241455/sum-i-1x-sum-j-1xfi-cdot-j-double-summing-a-not-completely-multipli

Answer (score 11):

One underappreciated but useful fact about multiplicative functions is the following: if $f(n)$ is multiplicative, and $k$ is any positive integer such that $f(k)\ne0$, then the function $g(n) = f(nk)/f(k)$ is a multiplicative function of $n$. (You'll get the proof correct on the first try.) In particular, we can write
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m\le x} \sum_{n\le x} f(mn) &= \sum_{m\le x} f(m) \sum_{n\le x} \frac{f(mn)}{f(m)}
\end{align*}
and use whatever techniques we want for sums of multiplicative functions on the inner sum. Using the Euler totient function as an example (quickly sketching the computation here):
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m\le x} \sum_{n\le x} \phi(mn) &= \sum_{m\le x} \phi(m) \sum_{n\le x} \frac{\phi(mn)}{\phi(m)} \\
&= \sum_{m\le x} \phi(m) \sum_{n\le x} \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ (d,m)=1}} \mu(d) \frac nd \\
&= \sum_{m\le x} \phi(m) \sum_{\substack{d\le x \\ (d,m)=1}} \frac{\mu(d)}d \sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ d\mid n}} n \\
&= \sum_{m\le x} \phi(m) \sum_{\substack{d\le x \\ (d,m)=1}} \mu(d) \sum_{m\le x/d} m \\
&\sim \sum_{m\le x} \phi(m) \sum_{\substack{d\le x \\ (d,m)=1}} \mu(d) \frac12 \bigg( \frac xd \bigg)^2 \\
&\sim \frac{x^2}2 \sum_{m\le x} \phi(m) \sum_{\substack{d\in\Bbb N \\ (d,m)=1}} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} \\
&= \frac{x^2}2 \frac1{\zeta(2)} \sum_{m\le x} \phi(m) \prod_{p\mid m} \bigg( 1-\frac1{p^2} \bigg)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{3x^2}{\pi^2} \sum_{m\le x} m \prod_{p\mid m} \frac p{p+1} \\
&\sim \frac{3x^2}{\pi^2} \frac{x^2}2 \prod_{p} \bigg( 1-\frac1p \bigg) \bigg( 1+ \frac p{p+1} \frac1p+ \frac p{p+1} \frac1{p^2} + \cdots \bigg) \\
&\sim \frac{3x^4}{2\pi^2} \prod_{p} \bigg( 1-\frac1{p(p+1)} \bigg) \approx 0.107062 x^4
\end{align*}
which is a good fit with experimental data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Different forms $f$ can take involve additional approaches for simplifying the sum, as can be shown from your $\phi$ example. Following on your excellent explanation, I am trying to extend this to the sum of divisors function, $\sigma(m\cdot n)$. Summing the divisors of different $n\leq x$ can be simplified greatly by running the sum over the divisors rather than the numbers themselves, with each divisor repeating $\lfloor \frac xd \rfloor$ times. This gives $\sum_{d=1}^x d\cdot \lfloor \frac xd \rfloor$. Can you show how this fits into your observation?

Comment: The reason I am interested in this, is that $\sum_{d=1}^x d\cdot \lfloor \frac xd \rfloor$ has an $O(n^{1/2+\epsilon})$ computation, using Dirichlet convolution.

Comment: The key starting step (very often, in my mind) is to find a way to write the multiplicative function $f(n)$ as $\sum_{d\mid n} g(d)$, then switch the order of summation to get $\sum_{n\le x} f(n) = \sum_{d\le x} g(d) \lfloor x/d\rfloor$. When $f=\sigma$ it's very easy, since $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} g(d)$ with $g(d)=d$; that's how the formula from your comment is proved. When $f(n) = \sigma(mn)/\sigma(m)$, the corresponding formula is $f(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} g(d)$ with $g(d) = d\prod_{p^k\|m,\,p\mid d} (1-(p^k-1)/(p^{k+1}-1))$ (found by looking at prime power inputs).

Comment: Also, the first line of the sum gives a different result from the 2nd line and forth. I tried both paper and computer calculations (which were the same, but differed between the first and second lines of the sum). For example, when $f=\sigma$, $S(5)$ results in $401$ on the first line, but $210$ on the second/third/fourth lines. Might there be a mistake?

Comment: Sorry, 1st/2nd/etc. lines of what?

Comment: One can't simply replace $\phi$ by $\sigma$ everywhere....

Comment: Rewriting my comment in a clear way: $\sum_{m\le x} \sigma(m) \sum_{n\le x} \frac{\sigma(mn)}{\sigma(m)}$ gives different result from $\sum_{m\le x} \sigma(m) \sum_{\substack{d\le x \\ (d,m)=1}} \mu(d) \sum_{m\le x/d} m \\$ for example, when i try to evaluate $S_\sigma(x)=\sum_{m\le x} \sum_{n\le x} \sigma(mn)$ for $x=5$. I thought your example was general for every (not completely) multiplicative function, and so I could replace $\phi$ with $\sigma$. Is there a similiar derivation for the sum of divisors $\sigma$ case? I would really appreciate if you could show it

Comment: The method is general, but the details differ for each function. See my earlier comments. I think at this point you'll benefit from deriving each equality by yourself one at a time, rather than trying to jump to the answer.